# Leaking to userspace via padding in a Kernel Module

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, padding

Looked at this code

```
    static int params_to_supp(struct tee_context *ctx,
                              struct tee_ioctl_param __user *uparams,
                              size_t num_params, struct tee_param *params)
    {
            size_t n;
    
            for (n = 0; n < num_params; n++) {
                    struct tee_ioctl_param ip;
                    struct tee_param *p = params + n;
    
                    ip.attr = p->attr;
                    switch (p->attr & TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_MASK) {
                    case TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_VALUE_INPUT:
                    case TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_VALUE_INOUT:
                            ip.a = p->u.value.a;
                            ip.b = p->u.value.b;
                            ip.c = p->u.value.c;
                            break;
                    case TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_MEMREF_INPUT:
                    case TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_MEMREF_OUTPUT:
                    case TEE_IOCTL_PARAM_ATTR_TYPE_MEMREF_INOUT:
                            ip.b = p->u.memref.size;
                            if (!p->u.memref.shm) {
                                    ip.a = 0;
                                    ip.c = (u64)-1; /* invalid shm id */
                                    break;
                            }
                            ip.a = p->u.memref.shm_offs;
                            ip.c = p->u.memref.shm->id;
                            break;
                    default:
                            ip.a = 0;
                            ip.b = 0;
                            ip.c = 0;
                            break;
                    }
    
                    if (copy_to_user(uparams + n, &ip, sizeof(ip)))
                            return -EFAULT;
            }
    
            return 0;
}
```

Get a warning that it could be potentially leaking memory on kernel stack, through padded fields, into user space.

However tee_ioctl_param fields, all are defined as u64

```
struct tee_ioctl_param {
    
__u64 attr;
    
__u64 a;
    
__u64 b;
    
__u64 c;
};
```

There is no padding happening, right?

Comment: What kernel version are you using? (e.g. this "feature" is a bit new). Is this a compiler warning or something that shows up in dmesg? Could you please _edit_ your question and post the _exact_ warning text in a separate code block. Also, it _may_ not be relevant, but could you post your other structs [so we could compile]? If you could post a complete file that compiles. It would only need the requisite `#include` and the function along with your module specific `struct` definitions. `copy_from_user` is now a wrapper to arch-specific calls. What is your arch (e.g. x86, arm)?

Comment: To see what I mean about being a wrapper, look at `linux/uaccess.h`. It does four or so lines before calling the arch specific `raw_*` version

Comment: Also, the checks that `copy_from_user` does are influenced by various `CONFIG_*` options (e.g. `CONFIG_HARDENED_USERCOPY`). So, could you also edit your post and put your `.config` in [yet] another code block?